# Why i can't select minimum android api level 15 from minimum api level dropdown (unity 2017 or higher)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So i'm using 2 android sdks "facebook sdk" + "google mobile ads sdk" in my android game, but when i try to select **Minimum API level 15** from the dropdown of the player settings, i can't find it there. **The minimum api level is 16 and higher in Unity 2017.0 and higher**. 
Is this a bug in the unity editor ?? Facebook sdk requires to select minimum api level 15 in order to work properly.

[image: Minimum api level 16]

Thanks for your help;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Unity removed support for **API level 15** and below. In fact, this really didn't happen in *Unity 2017.0* as you may have believed. This was done in the *Unity 5.6* version.

See Unity 5.6 release note for more info on this [here](https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.0).

> Android minimum version supported updated to 4.1 (JellyBean)

It's not a bug. Just go with *API level 16*.

Comment: but the only problem when i select api level 16, i have an error saying "unable to merge android manifests" when i try to build the apk. any suggestion ??

Comment: The problem you have with manifest is because of plugins you're using. There is likely a conflict between manifests. I suggest you create new question about this issue. In that question, mention your Unity version, List your plugins with all their versions, copy and paste the error(all the error during the build) and I am sure people can help you with those information provided.